# how to store data in plist and use them for table view

Tags: ios, xcode4.4

What should I write in Did select to pick data from Plist and use it in the table view for different data?

Answer (score 1):

To write data to plist, if you already have the data in a [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) or [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a), their respective `writeToFile` methods do this. Likewise to read from a plist, it's as simple as the respective `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` or `arrayWithContentsOfFile`.

This topic is covered further in the Apple [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i).

Anyway, to write to a plist (note, I am writing the plist from the `Documents` folder, because you cannot write files to your bundle):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mo", @"Larry", @"Curly", nil];
NSString *documentFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPath = [documentFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

[array writeToFile:documentPath atomically:YES];
```

To read from a plist (note, I happen to be reading the plist I created above, but clearly you can read plists from your bundle (using Rocky's technique) or from your `Documents` folder):

```
NSString *documentFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPath = [documentFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

_array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:documentPath];
```

You could then use that array (or dictionary, if you used that) to populate your table view.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistfilename" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

it will help you.